# Json path starting with 0

Tags: javascript, json, https

I'm trying to get the data from a https.get request to an API and the json path has a 0 at the beginning. What does it mean and how do I access the data?

```
 https.get(url, function(response) {
    response.on("data", function(data) {
      readableData = JSON.parse(data);
      length = readableData.0.length; // <-- inserting path (0.length) here doesnt work as usually
```

The path is 0.length and the json chart viewer throws an error.

The data looks like this in json viewer:

```
[
  {
    "length": "32260db8-40d3-4973-9031-ceef149189aa",
  }
]
```

Comment: `readableData.0` isn't valid JS (bare properties cannot start with a number), so what _actual_ data are you working with? Because at the very least, that should be `readableData[0]` if readableData is an array, or `readableData["0"]` if readableData is an object.

Comment: JSON is string data: just show that data in a code block (and obviously not the _entire_ JSON object, just show the parts relevant to this question)

Comment: Updated the question. I know that it's not valid JS. Copying the path and adding it to readableData always works usually, but in this case something is off. It seems like i can't access that data.

Comment: The JSON you're showing is an array containing a single objects in position 0, and that object has a property called `length` that has a value that appears to have _nothing to do_ with lengths, but that's neither here nor there. Simply use the JS syntax for getting the 0th element and then access its `.length`

Comment: Yes I deleted the other few objects and changed its name to length. That doesn't change the problem that I do not know how to get the value of that length. As already meantioned, json viewer gives me the path 0.length and the chart tree throws an error.

Comment: And that's a "json viewer path", not JS. To actually get your data in JS, _use proper JS syntax_ for accessing array elements, as already noted in the very first comment: `readableData[0]`, not `readableData.0`

Comment: yes I'm new to web dev and it's so obvious but i didn't think of it as an array containing objects. thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0` is index of array, to get length of the array do

```
readableData.length; // 1
```

to select first array do

```
readableData[0].length; // 32260db8-40d3-4973-9031-ceef149189aa
```

Comment: thanks, didn't think of it as an array and the json viewer path confused me.